# C# Extracting String and Double from line of string

Tags: c#, string, text-extraction

I have a line from which I need to extract a Name and the result (double) of that name.

The line looks like this:

```
James: 8, John: 8, Jasmin: 12, Igor: 1.54, Garry: 0, Gabe: 0.12, Lauren: 0, Grace: 81.31
```

I need each of them as an array of Name and Amount.

I tried to use regex but quite failed. Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: No need for a regex: split with `", "` and then split each item with `": "`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment says, you don't need regex, just split. Something like that works:

```
string str = "James: 8, John: 8, Jasmin: 12, Igor: 1.54, Garry: 0, Gabe: 0.12, Lauren: 0, Grace: 81.31";
var values = str.Split(',');
(string name, double value)[] result = new (string, double)[values.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    var splittedValue = values[i].Split(':');
    result[i] = (splittedValue[0], Double.Parse(splittedValue[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

Comment: should be the cleanest way, i would take care of whitespaces, trimming the splits itself should do the trick

Comment: trimming can be usefull for the names part, but it's automaticaly done when parsing

Comment: you're right, it was just meant for the sake of error tolerance ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As the line is regular you can get away with one split:

```
string str = "James: 8, John: 8, Jasmin: 12, Igor: 1.54, Garry: 0, Gabe: 0.12, Lauren: 0, Grace: 81.31";

var values = str.Split(',',':');
(string name, double value)[] result = new (string, double)[values.Length/2];
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i+=2)
    result[i/2] = (values[i].Trim(), Convert.ToDouble(values[i+1]));
```